# Flexbox on a single section

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, css-selectors

I have a single section in all my HTML, where I need to use flexboxes. The below CSS is affecting all the rows and columns in my HTML. I need the below CSS code only to affect the HTML I have posted here.

How can I make that happen?

Best regards

```css
.row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.row>[class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="bestseller-wrap">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color: aqua;">
        <h3>Here is a headline</h3>
        <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <img src="/img/test.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.bestseller-wrap .row` and `.bestseller-wrap .row>[class*='col-']` as selectors to only affect the rows and columns in this element.

If you need to tie it to the section itself, apply a class to the section in HTML and use that class instead of `.bestseller-wrap`

```css
.bestseller-wrap .row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.bestseller-wrap .row>[class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="bestseller-wrap">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color: aqua;">
        <h3>Here is a headline</h3>
        <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <img src="/img/test.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

Just add a class!

```css
.section-headline .row {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.section-headline .row>[class*='col-'] {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="section section-headline">
  <div class="bestseller-wrap">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color: aqua;">
        <h3>Here is a headline</h3>
         <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <img src="/img/test.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <h5>A different row</h5>
</div>
```